# I'm getting this problem in vue trying to display a graphic with apexcharts?

Tags: vue.js

I work with vue and apexchart. I call the api with the async method, to make sure that I am showing the correct information. I'm using console.Log and the array is correct. So does anyone know what is happening here? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your graph is created before the data of your api arrives. Try this :

```
data: () => ({
  series: null
  options: { ... }
}),

async mounted() {
  this.loaded = false;
  try {
    const res = await fetch(urlYandex);
    const json = await res.json()
    this.series = json.data[0].metrics[0];
    this.loaded = true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
},
```

your apexchart you add like this :

```
<apexchart :options="options" :series="series" v-if="loaded"></apexchart>
```